# Proving the transform of the Q-function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

I have the Gaussian Q-function, given by:

[image]

and I want to prove that it can be also expressed as:

[image]

Can somebody help explaining how to obtain the second integral from the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give one possible approach here. Four other recently given methods to show this result can be found [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/some-alternative-derivations-of-craigs-formula/DE7405D526DF9E9D344CBC2FAA745EBA).

We begin by noting that
$$Q(x) = \frac{1}{2} \text{erfc} \left (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right ), \qquad (\dagger)$$
where $\text{erfc} (x)$ is the *complementary error function* define by
$$\text{erfc} (x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int^\infty_x e^{-u^2} \, du.$$ The result ($\dagger$) is obtained from your definition for the $Q$-function using a substitution of $t \sqrt{2}$ for $y$.

We start by considering the function
$$I(x) = \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-x^2 t^2}}{1 + t^2} \, dt, \quad x > 0.$$
On differentiating under the integral sign (using Feynman's trick) we have
$$I'(x) = -2x \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^2}{1 + t^2} e^{-x^2 t^2} \, dt.$$
Noting that
$$\frac{t^2}{1 + t^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + t^2},$$
our expression for $I'(x)$ can be rewritten as
$$I'(x) = -2x \int^\infty_0 e^{-x^2 t^2} \, dt + 2x \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-x^2 t^2}}{1 + t^2} \, dt = -\sqrt{\pi} + 2x I(x), \qquad (*)$$
were the well-known result for the value of the Gaussian (probability) integral for the first integral has been used after a substitution of $u = xt$ has been made.

Eq. ($*$) is a first-order linear differential equation. An integrating factor for this equation is $R(x) = e^{-x^2}$. Thus one can rewrite the linear differential equation in the following separable form
$$\frac{d}{dx} [e^{-x^2} I(x)] = - \sqrt{\pi} e^{-x^2}.$$
On separating and integrating we have
$$e^{-x^2} I(x) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int^x_0 e^{-u^2} \, du + C. \qquad (**)$$
To find the value for the arbitrary constant $C$, let $x \to 0^+$. From the definition for our function $I(x)$, when this is done we find 
$$I(x) \to \int^\infty_0 \frac{dt}{1 + t^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Now letting $x \to 0^+$ in Eq. ($**$) we find $C = \pi/2$. So Eq. ($**$), can be written as
$$e^{-x^2} I(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \left [1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int^x_0 e^{-u^2} \, du \right ]. \qquad (\ddagger)$$
Recalling the *error function* $\text{erf} (x)$, which is defined as
$$\text{erf} (x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int^x_0 e^{-u^2} \, du,$$
is related to its complement by $\text{erf} (x) + \text{erfc} (x) = 1$, Eq. ($\ddagger$), becomes
$$e^{-x^2} I(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{erfc} (x),$$
which after rearranging may be written as
$$\text{erfc} (x) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-x^2(1 + t^2)}}{1 + t^2} \, dt.$$
Making a substitution of $t = \cot \theta$ it follows that
$$Q(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \exp \left (-\frac{x^2}{2 \sin^2 \theta} \right ) \, d\theta, \quad x > 0,$$
while if a substitution of $t = \tan \theta$ is made, as a bonus, we get
$$Q(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \exp \left (-\frac{x^2}{2 \cos^2 \theta} \right ) \, d\theta, \quad x > 0$$
almost for free!

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions tend to zero as $x\to +\infty$, so it is sufficient to show that their derivatives agree.

Assume that $x>0$ (I leave the other case to you). Let us differentiate the second integral,
$$
Q'(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\exp(-x^2/(2\sin^2\theta))\frac{x}{\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta.
$$
Now,
$$
\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}=1+\cot^2\theta,
$$
so, with $y=x\cot\theta$ it holds that $dy=-x/\sin^2\theta\,d\theta$, and hence
$$
Q'(x)=-\exp(-x^2/2)\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\exp(-y^2/2)\,dy=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2).
$$
Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we see that the derivative of the first expression agrees with what we just found.

Comment: Many thanks...but can you please also try to reach the second Q-function integral from the first one? I want to see what substitution it might be used to reach the second integral.

Comment: I don't see such a substitution right away, but maybe you could live with what is done in the answer, together with $Q_1(x)=Q_1(0)+\int_0^x Q_1'(y)\,dy=Q_2(0)+\int_0^x Q_2'(y)\,dy=Q_2(x)$... or wait for someone else to come up with something.